# How to add header in Apollo GraphQL : iOS

Tags: ios, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Hy I am working in a project with `Apollo GraphQL` method and its working fine. But now the client required for adding additional header with Apollo API's. But after adding the header the API's response return as *unAuthorized*.

I am adding the header as,

```
    let apolloAuth: ApolloClient = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        // Add additional headers as needed
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : self.singleTonInstance.token]
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["channel" : "mobile"]

        let url = URL(string: "http://xxx/graphql")!

        return ApolloClient(networkTransport: HTTPNetworkTransport(url: url, configuration: configuration))

    }()
```

Anyone please help me to find out how to add headers with Apollo GraphQL.

Comment: Did you try to set the header to "Bearer <token>" instead of "<token>"? What's the authorization method your server is using? Do you have a working cURL statement against the server that uses an authorization token?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Please refer my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. Add the header in the following way,

```
 let apolloAuth: ApolloClient = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        let token = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "token")
        // Add additional headers as needed
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["authorization":"\(token!)", "channel":"mobile"]
        let url = URL(string: "http://xxxx/graphql")!

        return ApolloClient(networkTransport: HTTPNetworkTransport(url: url, configuration: configuration))

    }()
```

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: it stops working from version 0.34, there is no HTTPNetworkTransport anymore

Answer (score 19):

**UPDATE: Solution for "Apollo Client v0.41.0" and "Swift 5"**

I had the same issue with Apollo Client v0.41.0 and Swift 5.0 but none of the above solutions worked. Finally able to find a solution after the hours of try-out. The below solution is tested with Apollo Client v0.41.0 And Swift 5

```
import Foundation
import Apollo

class Network {
    static let shared = Network()
    
    private(set) lazy var apollo: ApolloClient = {

        let cache = InMemoryNormalizedCache()
        let store1 = ApolloStore(cache: cache)
        let authPayloads = ["Authorization": "Bearer <<TOKEN>>"]
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = authPayloads
        
        let client1 = URLSessionClient(sessionConfiguration: configuration, callbackQueue: nil)
        let provider = NetworkInterceptorProvider(client: client1, shouldInvalidateClientOnDeinit: true, store: store1)
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://<HOST NAME>/graphql")!
        
        let requestChainTransport = RequestChainNetworkTransport(interceptorProvider: provider,
                                                                 endpointURL: url)
        
        return ApolloClient(networkTransport: requestChainTransport,
                            store: store1)
    }()
}
class NetworkInterceptorProvider: DefaultInterceptorProvider {
    override func interceptors<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(for operation: Operation) -> [ApolloInterceptor] {
        var interceptors = super.interceptors(for: operation)
        interceptors.insert(CustomInterceptor(), at: 0)
        return interceptors
    }
}

class CustomInterceptor: ApolloInterceptor {
    
    func interceptAsync<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(
        chain: RequestChain,
        request: HTTPRequest<Operation>,
        response: HTTPResponse<Operation>?,
        completion: @escaping (Swift.Result<GraphQLResult<Operation.Data>, Error>) -> Void) {
        request.addHeader(name: "Authorization", value: "Bearer <<TOKEN>>")
        
        print("request :\(request)")
        print("response :\(String(describing: response))")
        
        chain.proceedAsync(request: request,
                           response: response,
                           completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution that works with Apollo 0.42.0

Comment: @Chamath Jeevan I have tried this solution with Apollo 0.43.0 version and it gives me failure reposne error as **failure(Apollo.LegacyParsingInterceptor.LegacyParsingError.couldNotParseToLegacyJSON(data: 1839 bytes))** please suggest me what can I do further

Comment: @JochenHolzer I too have tried the same code syntax but the request gives me HTML in failure block. Could you please help me to solve this issue [Apollo GraphQL header always gives failure in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318381/apollo-graphql-header-always-gives-failure-in-ios-swift)

Comment: @Princess Perhaps there is an error message in the HTML response. If I were you, I would ask the endpoint development team what information about your failed request is in the server log files.

Comment: @JochenHolzer I am using a Shopify GraphQL Admin API to fetch customer's order details from the Shopify store. The same URL request working with Android Apollo Client.

Comment: This worked for 0.51.2 version. Note: Tokens expires. So using singleton won't work. Apollo recommends using UserManagementInterceptor for expiring tokens. https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/discussions/1535

Comment: Can you update it to version 1.0

Answer (score 10):

As of Apollo Client v0.34.0 and above the code provided earlier won't work since they rewrote how it used to work. Here is what worked for me... For more information consider going through this documentation in the link [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/initialization/#sample-usermanagementinteceptor).

```
class Network {
  static let shared = Network()
  
    private(set) lazy var apollo: ApolloClient = {
        let client = URLSessionClient()
        let cache = InMemoryNormalizedCache()
        let store = ApolloStore(cache: cache)
        let provider = NetworkInterceptorProvider(client: client, store: store)
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.graphqlapi.com/")!
        let transport = RequestChainNetworkTransport(interceptorProvider: provider,
                                                     endpointURL: url)
        return ApolloClient(networkTransport: transport)
    }()
}

class NetworkInterceptorProvider: LegacyInterceptorProvider {
    override func interceptors<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(for operation: Operation) -> [ApolloInterceptor] {
        var interceptors = super.interceptors(for: operation)
        interceptors.insert(CustomInterceptor(), at: 0)
        return interceptors
    }
}

class CustomInterceptor: ApolloInterceptor {
    // Find a better way to store your token this is just an example
    let token = "YOUR TOKEN"
    
    func interceptAsync<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(
        chain: RequestChain,
        request: HTTPRequest<Operation>,
        response: HTTPResponse<Operation>?,
        completion: @escaping (Result<GraphQLResult<Operation.Data>, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        request.addHeader(name: "authorization", value: "Bearer: \(token)")

        chain.proceedAsync(request: request,
                           response: response,
                           completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Comment: What a nightmare API! `NetworkInterceptorProvider: LegacyInterceptorProvider`!

Answer (score 6):

The accepted solution is now outdated as the HTTPNetworkTransport no longer takes in a configuration argument, instead accepting a `URLSession` directly rather than a `URLSessionConfiguration`

Here's an example how to send an authorization header on every request to Apollo Client, retrieving it, if found, from UserDefaults in `version 0.21.0` of Apollo Client(iOS)

```
import Foundation
import Apollo

class Network {
    static let shared = Network()

    private(set) lazy var apollo: ApolloClient = {
        let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "accessToken") ?? ""
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:4000/graphql")!

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]

        return ApolloClient(
            networkTransport: HTTPNetworkTransport(url: url, session: URLSession(configuration: configuration))
        )
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### UPDATE: This solution is deprecated after "Apollo Client v0.34.0"

The previous answers are old, this is now done through a delegate:

> "This protocol allows pre-flight validation of requests, the ability to bail out before modifying the request, and the ability to modify the URLRequest with things like additional headers."

```
import Foundation
import Apollo

    final class Network {
        static let shared = Network()
        private lazy var networkTransport: HTTPNetworkTransport = {        

        let transport = HTTPNetworkTransport(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/graphql")!)
        transport.delegate = self

        return transport
    }()

    private(set) lazy var apollo = ApolloClient(networkTransport: self.networkTransport)
}

extension Network: HTTPNetworkTransportPreflightDelegate {
    func networkTransport(_ networkTransport: HTTPNetworkTransport, shouldSend request: URLRequest) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func networkTransport(_ networkTransport: HTTPNetworkTransport, willSend request: inout URLRequest) {
        var headers = request.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [String: String]()
        headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer \(YOUR_TOKEN)"

        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the documentation for more details:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/initialization/

Comment: Am getting this errors `Cannot find type 'HTTPNetworkTransport' in scope` and `Cannot find type 'HTTPNetworkTransportPreflightDelegate' in scope` any help? Am using Appoloclient v0.34.1.

Comment: @GB
 I checked out the docs in the link above, and they have deprecated HTPPNetworkTransport. 

This can still be done using "LegacyInterceptorProvider", or you could look into the new protocol: NetworkTransport".

Comment: I provided a solution you can have a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

Import these two elements

```
import UIKit
import Apollo
```

Create a class Network and paste below source code

```
    struct Network {
    static var request = Network()
    private(set) lazy var apollo: ApolloClient = {

        let cache = InMemoryNormalizedCache()
        let store1 = ApolloStore(cache: cache)
        let authPayloads = ["Authorization": "Bearer <TOKEN>"]
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = authPayloads
        
        let client1 = URLSessionClient(sessionConfiguration: configuration, callbackQueue: nil)
        let provider = NetworkInterceptorProvider(client: client1, shouldInvalidateClientOnDeinit: true, store: store1)
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://xxx/graphql")!
        
        let requestChainTransport = RequestChainNetworkTransport(interceptorProvider: provider,
                                                                 endpointURL: url)
        
        return ApolloClient(networkTransport: requestChainTransport,
                            store: store1)
    }()
}
```

add NetworkInterceptorProvider in Network class

```
class NetworkInterceptorProvider: LegacyInterceptorProvider {
override func interceptors<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(for operation: Operation) -> [ApolloInterceptor] {
    var interceptors = super.interceptors(for: operation)
    interceptors.insert(CustomInterceptor(), at: 0)
    return interceptors
}
```

}

add CustomInterceptor also in Network class

```
class CustomInterceptor: ApolloInterceptor {

func interceptAsync<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(
    chain: RequestChain,
    request: HTTPRequest<Operation>,
    response: HTTPResponse<Operation>?,
    completion: @escaping (Swift.Result<GraphQLResult<Operation.Data>, Error>) -> Void) {
    request.addHeader(name: "Authorization", value: "Bearer <TOKEN>")
    
    print("request :\(request)")
    print("response :\(String(describing: response))")
    
    chain.proceedAsync(request: request,
                       response: response,
                       completion: completion)
}
```

}

finally call this method from ViewController

```
func todoQueryCloud(){
    Network.request.apollo.fetch(query: ProgressionsQuery()){result in
        // 3
        switch result {
        case .success(let graphQLResult):
            guard let data = try? result.get().data else { return }
            if graphQLResult.data != nil {
                // 4
                print("Loaded data \(String(describing: data.progressions))")
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
            
        case .failure(let error):
            // 5
            print("Error loading data \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For me this isn't working I have asked a new question [Apollo GraphQL header always gives failure in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318381/apollo-graphql-header-always-gives-failure-in-ios-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1) please check this.

Answer (score 1):

**NetworkInterceptorProvider: LegacyInterceptorProvider changed as a "DefaultInterceptorProvider"**

```
class NetworkInterceptorProvider: DefaultInterceptorProvider {
override func interceptors<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(for operation: Operation) -> [ApolloInterceptor] {
    var interceptors = super.interceptors(for: operation)
    interceptors.insert(CustomInterceptor(), at: 0)
    return interceptors
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I've been following the tutorial on https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/tutorial/tutorial-execute-first-query

and if just adding a custom header is your goal, then the simplest way to do so is

```
import Apollo
import Foundation

class Network {
    static let shared = Network()

    private(set) lazy var apollo: ApolloClient = {
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/v1/graphql")!

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer token"] // Add your headers here

        let client = URLSessionClient(sessionConfiguration: configuration)
        let store = ApolloStore(cache: InMemoryNormalizedCache())
        let provider = DefaultInterceptorProvider(client: client, store: store)
        let networkTransport = RequestChainNetworkTransport(interceptorProvider: provider, endpointURL: url)

        return ApolloClient(networkTransport: networkTransport, store: store)
    }()
}
```

hope this can be of help!

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution for Apollo 1.6.1

```
import Foundation
import Apollo

class DataCoordinator: NSObject {
    // MARK: Variables
    static let shared: DataCoordinator = DataCoordinator()
    private(set) lazy var apolloClient: ApolloClient = {
        let cache = InMemoryNormalizedCache()
        let store = ApolloStore(cache: cache)
        let authPayloads = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = authPayloads
        let client = URLSessionClient(sessionConfiguration: configuration, callbackQueue: nil)
        let provider = NetworkInterceptorProvider(store: store, client: client)
        let url = URL(string: "https://xxxxxxxxx/graphql")!
        let requestChainTransport = RequestChainNetworkTransport(interceptorProvider: provider, endpointURL: url)
        return ApolloClient(networkTransport: requestChainTransport, store: store)
    }()
}

struct NetworkInterceptorProvider: InterceptorProvider {
    // These properties will remain the same throughout the life of the `InterceptorProvider`, even though they
    // will be handed to different interceptors.
    private let store: ApolloStore
    private let client: URLSessionClient
    
    init(store: ApolloStore,
         client: URLSessionClient) {
        self.store = store
        self.client = client
    }
    
    func interceptors<Operation>(for operation: Operation) -> [ApolloInterceptor] {
        return [
            MaxRetryInterceptor(),
            CacheReadInterceptor(store: self.store),
            NetworkFetchInterceptor(client: self.client),
            ResponseCodeInterceptor(),
            JSONResponseParsingInterceptor(),
            AutomaticPersistedQueryInterceptor(),
            CacheWriteInterceptor(store: self.store)
        ]
    }
}
```

Happy Coding ...